# How to rig animation of Mixamo Characters in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, fbx, mixamo

I am trying to give movements to different body parts of a Mixamo Characters.
The method that I am trying involves rotating each bone and seems very naive. Is their any wrapper over three.js which can help build new movement animations in human characters?

I don't want to use the standard animations available on Mixamo.com.

Answer (score 0):

Animations are usually made in modelling software such as Blender, and then exported and loaded into THREE.js.

Blender is free and amazing. I *highly* recommmend learning it if you have any interest in 3d content generation/games/animation.